# Accessing a list at a certain index

Tags: foreach, comma-separated-list, pgffor

I want to define the following command, which is to render an arbitrary number of subfigures. The argument is a nested list:

```
\multifig{{{fig_1, T0D0, TODO}, {fig_2, T0D0, TODO}}}
```

Is the following possible?

```
\newcommand*{\multifig}[1]{
\begin{figure}
\foreach \x in #1 {
    \begin{subfigure}{\somewidth\textwidth}
    % here I need the element at index 1 of the list \x. how?
    \customfig{\x at 1}
    \end{subfigure}
}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to use `pgffor` or would another solution be accepted?

Comment: I'm happy with any way to loop over a list of lists and then access the inner list by index.

Comment: What do `fig_1`, `T0D0` and `TODO` represent? Perhaps you want to access all three items. Can you specify more clearly what `\customfig` should do?

Comment: fig_1 is the name of a figure. T0D0 and TODO are captions. I want to access all of them, but they represent different things. So I need to access each one by index explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives you access to a specific item of a (sub)list using expl3.

In its current state it will produce a figure with subfigures and the first item of the sublist printed (change `\__gerry_customfig` to alter that behavior). Please note that I have set the subfigures to a fixed width by now (I do not know your `\somewidth`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__gerry_mycl
\cs_new:Npn \__gerry_customfig:n #1 {
    \detokenize{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\multifig}{m}{
\begin{figure}
\clist_set:Nn \l__gerry_mycl {#1}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l__gerry_mycl {
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1}
    \exp_args:Nx \__gerry_customfig:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1}}
    \end{subfigure}
}
\end{figure}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\multifig{{fig_1, T0D0, TODO}, {fig_2, T0D0, TODO}}
\end{document}
```