# TeX capacity exceeded in figure captions

Tags: graphics, captions, expl3, latex3, capacity

I got provided with the following code to define a macro for an image composed of any number of subfigures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__gerry_mycl
\cs_new:Npn \__gerry_customfiggg:n #1#2#3#4 {
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}
% caption produces tex capacity exceeded.
    \caption[#3]{#4}
    \label{fig:#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\multifig}{m}{
\begin{figure}
\clist_set:Nn \l__gerry_mycl {#1}
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l__gerry_mycl {
        \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1}
        \begin{subfigure}{{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1}}\textwidth}
        \exp_args:Nx \__gerry_customfiggg:n {0.95}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2}}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3}\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {4}}
        \end{subfigure}
}
\end{figure}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

% size, file name, caption, caption
\multifig{{.2, fig_1, small caption 1, big caption 1}, {.1, fig_2, small caption 2, big caption 2}}

\end{document}
```

(source: [Accessing a list at a certain index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372911/accessing-a-list-at-a-certain-index))

The command `\caption[]{}` produces the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\caption@ifstrut #1#2->#1
```

When defining figures explicitly the problem does not appear. I would really like to define the macro though. Is there a way to get it working?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, that's probably a problem of expansion.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean the line `\exp_args:Nx \__gerry_customfiggg:n {0.95}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2}}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3}\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {4}}`?

Comment: No, the part with the subfigure and it's integer is the first problem, then the part with the `\exp_args`.

Comment: Why `\__gerry_custom_figgg:n` and not \__gerry_custom_figgg:nnnn`, then defining an `nxxx` variant?

Comment: @TeXnician: The `{\clist_item:Nn ... }\textwidth}` is wrong, in my opinion, yes

Comment: Indeed I have no understanding of expl3. I just want to get this macro to work. So by problem with dimensions you mean that the original was meant for one argument and I am passing 4? How do I fix that?

Comment: When I compile the original version, I get the `! Missing number, treated as zero.` error, indicating an evaluation/expanding problem of number/dimension, but no `capacity` error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1}}\textwidth` in my point of view, it does not expand to the correct dimension (multiple).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__gerry_mycl


\cs_new:Nn \__gerry_customfiggg:nnnn {
  \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}
  % caption produces tex capacity exceeded.
  \caption[#3]{#4}
  \label{fig:#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\multifig}{m}{
  \begin{figure}
    \clist_set:Nn \l__gerry_mycl {#1}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__gerry_mycl {
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1}
      \begin{subfigure}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1}\textwidth}
        \__gerry_customfiggg:nnnn {0.95}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2}}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3}}{\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {4}}
      \end{subfigure}
    }
  \end{figure}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

% size, file name, caption, caption
\multifig{{.2, ente, small caption 1, big caption 1}, {.1, ente1, small caption 2, big caption 2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. You are completely right to believe that I have no idea about expl3. In my defense, it looks nothing like any language I have ever seen.

Comment: @Gerry: Compared to TeX or LaTeX(2e) the syntax of `expl3` might look weird at first -- but speaking with Darth Vader: Don't underestimate the Power of Expl3 ;-)

Comment: I will update with a solution with respects the `naming conventions` of `expl3` later on

Answer (score 4):

Your internal function should be named differently, as it has four arguments.

Also, `\exp_args:Nx` will not do what you expect, because it just expands the contents of the first braced group after the next token. Actually, this is not really needed, but I left it just by way of example.

You should define a variant that expands *all* arguments. By the way, you need no clist variable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__gerry_customfiggg:nnnn #1#2#3#4
 {
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}
    \caption[#3]{#4}
    \label{fig:#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__gerry_customfiggg:nnnn { xxxx }

\NewDocumentCommand{\multifig}{m}
 {
    \begin{figure}
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
     {
        \begin{subfigure}{\clist_item:nn {##1}{1}\textwidth}
        \__gerry_customfiggg:xxxx % \__gerry_customfiggg:nnnn would do as well
          {0.95}
          {\clist_item:nn {##1}{2}}
          {\clist_item:nn {##1}{3}}
          {\clist_item:nn {##1}{4}}
        \end{subfigure}
}
\end{figure}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

% size, file name, caption, caption
\multifig{
  {.2, example-image-a, small caption 1, big caption 1},
  {.1, example-image-b, small caption 2, big caption 2}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I'd favor a completely different and much more flexible approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { gerry/multifig }
 {
  align .tl_set:N        = \l_gerry_multifig_align_tl,
  scale .tl_set:N        = \l_gerry_multifig_scale_tl,
  innerscale .tl_set:N   = \l_gerry_multifig_innerscale_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N      = \l_gerry_multifig_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_gerry_multifig_shortcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N        = \l_gerry_multifig_label_tl,
  align .initial:n       = c,
  scale .initial:n       = 1,
  innerscale .initial:n  = 0.95,
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{multifig}{O{htp}}
 {
  \begin{figure}[#1]
 }
 {
  \end{figure}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\shortfig}{mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { gerry/multifig } { #2 }
  \begin{subfigure}[\l_gerry_multifig_align_tl]{\l_gerry_multifig_scale_tl\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\l_gerry_multifig_innerscale_tl\textwidth]{#1}
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_gerry_multifig_shortcaption_tl
   {
    \caption{\l_gerry_multifig_caption_tl}
   }
   {
    \caption[\l_gerry_multifig_shortcaption_tl]{\l_gerry_multifig_caption_tl}
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_gerry_multifig_label_tl { \label{\l_gerry_multifig_label_tl} }
  \end{subfigure}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\ref{examplelabel}

\begin{multifig}
\shortfig{example-image-a}{
  scale=.2,
  shortcaption=small caption 1,
  caption=big caption 1,
  label=examplelabel,
}\qquad
\shortfig{example-image-b}{
  align=t,
  scale=.2,
  innerscale=.5,
  caption=caption 2,
 }
\end{multifig}

\begin{multifig}
\shortfig{example-image-a}{
  align=t,
  scale=.2,
  shortcaption=small caption 1,
  caption=big caption 1,
}\qquad
\shortfig{example-image-b}{
  align=t,
  scale=.2,
  innerscale=.5,
  caption=caption 2,
 }
\end{multifig}

\end{document}
```

[image]